# Is there a term for roman-type Arabic numerals?

Tags: typefaces, terminology

There are [Roman numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numeral) and [Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numeral) (perhaps more accurately Indo-Arabic numerals) and there also are three main branches of typefaces for the Latin alphabet: [roman type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_type), [blackletter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackletter) and [Gaelic type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaelic_type). Now the latter styles can are sometimes applied to Arabic numerals, creating a distinction between blackletter (Arabic) numerals, Gaelic (Arabic) numerals and … – well, that’s my question.

- *Roman-type numerals* are too easily confused with *roman numerals.*
- *Roman-type Arabic numerals* is probably accurate but somewhat clumsy and would probably still confuse many readers.
- *Default numerals* or *default Arabic numerals* requires some context as to what the *default* is contrasting with. From the reader’s point of view, I might as well refer to uppercase numerals to contrast them with lowercase numerals.

Is there any technical term for these numerals?

---

[image: Illustrative examples]

Answer (score 1):

The numerals with ascenders and descenders are called "old style numerals" or "old style figures"; the ones that are a consistent height are called "lining numerals" or "lining figures". "Roman" has been diluted to the point that it's not easily translatable to a mind picture anymore; it's applied to grotesques and some gothics as well as to classic book serif faces in computer font drop-down lists. Civilians won't understand those terms anyway, though, so you will need to have examples handy.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers my question. The distinction between uppercase/lining numerals and lowercase/oldstyle/text numerals is not what I am after (and in fact, I used both kinds as examples). That *Roman* alone is not a useful adjective (even amongst non-civilians) is the source of my problem.

Comment: Q: "Is there any technical term for these numerals?" --> A: Old Style Figures (as mentioned in this answer) or add precision to the question: http://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/numbers/oldstyle-figures